# What holds Dormammu to Dr. Strange's bargain?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange, doctor-strange-2016

At the end of [*Doctor Strange*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Strange_(film)), the doctor

> makes a bargain with Dormammu, turning off the infinite time loop in exchange for leaving the Earth alone, and never coming back.

When I saw this, I immediately wondered, **what holds Dormammu to this bargain?** Once

> the time loop is turned off,

why not kill Strange and company? He is no longer threatened at that point.

For a graphic representation of this question, see the YouTube clip, below:

---

NB: this is similar to, but not the same as [Is there another way out for Dormammu?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/144202/41144) -- that question asked about *before* the bargain; I am asking about *after* the bargain.

Comment: Many supernatural entities are bound to the deals they make. It’s a common feature in fantasy.

Comment: Probably fear that if he goes back on his bargain, Strange (or someone else on Earth) has the ability to trap him again, this time for eternity.

Comment: I'd upvote and probably accept an answer that *showed* that to be the case here, @Adamant. Is there any canonical info on whether or not that's true for Dormammu?

Comment: Well, there is this info about a similar thing from the Marvel wiki: “Before the gathered Lords, Strange forced Dormammu’s *vow to menace Earth no further even by proxy*, cementing the Dread One’s humiliation. However, Dormammu struck a parting blow by extradimensionally banishing Clea, and then manipulating fellow Nether-Lord Tazza into attacking the sorcerer.” And also: “Indebted to Strange for his help, Dormammu felt compelled to end the fight, and Strange made him vow never to threaten the Earth dimension again.” I would have to find the sources to show that Dormammu keeps his word.

Comment: @Valorum Maybe. But if (as HISHE shows) Dormammu kills Strange quickly (and we know that D can kill Strange; he's shown doing that many times in the film), then there shouldn't be much to worry about.

Comment: But I am almost certain that’s what’s going on here. It’s an omnipresent theme: supernatural entities are kept to their promises. Greek gods swearing on the River Styx, deals with the Devil, etc.

Comment: It certainly *feels* right, @Adamant; I agree with you on that. I'd still like something canonical, if possible. (Also, a different but related question: does Strange *know* this to be true at the beginning, when he goes to strike this bargain? Otherwise it's a pretty stupid idea)

Comment: @Shokhet - He already tried killing Strange (over and over again).

Comment: @Valorum Successfully. Strange just loops back every time

Comment: @Shokhet - Why would the monster assume that this time would be any different?

Comment: What @Valorum said. Isn't the threat of being trapped in a time loop forever enough?

Comment: @JDoe Doesn't Strange turn the loop off after D agrees to the bargain? (Time continues and the green disappears from his arms)

Comment: @Shokhet I have no idea. I bet Dormammu has no idea either. Remember, he was surprised and incapacitated by the trap. It's also said that he comes from (is?) a dimension with no time. So why would you think that Dormammu would know of the limits of the Eye of Agamotto, which he has never encountered before, or even understand how time really works? What he *does* know is that Strange is willing and able to trap him forever, and that is enough.

Comment: Because "Dormammu, I've come to bargain."

Comment: Why go through all that trouble of the unknown when he can just leave them alone.

Comment: Now similar question on movies.se too [Why did Dormammu keep his promise?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93864/why-did-dormammu-keep-his-promise)

Answer (score 11):

### Probably some supernatural bond

This promise that Dormammu makes (not to attack Earth directly) is taken straight from the comic universe, though the context is different.

[image]

In the comics, Dormammu has a rigid morality. According to Strange:

> STRANGE: He is evil, true…but only by our *human* standards. According to his
>   *own* lights, he has his own moral code!

Whether there is something *supernatural* to this is unclear. **It seems very likely, though.** Other media (not canon to the comics or movies, naturally) do imply as much. For example, the [Infernal Promise card](http://marvel-war-of-heroes.wikia.com/wiki/Infernal_Promise_Dormammu) from Marvel’s War of Heroes card game.

> Mortal! Do not take lightly the oaths of Dread Dormammu! **There is
>   power in the promises of beings such as myself!** I will honor any
>   agreement between us! But a simple misstep on your part might undo our
>   arrangement! And when that happens, Dormammu will owe you no such
>   thing as mercy!

More generally, supernatural beings are often depicted as being forced to keep their word: Faeries not lying, Greek gods taking oaths of the River Styx, deals with the Devil.

Would Strange know this, though? Probably. He *has* been studying magic for some time, and **probably knows the rules that bind entities such as Dormammu**. Even if he doesn’t, can we be sure he’d *really* be willing to be stuck in a loop for all eternity? Perhaps he’s simply taking a chance, and hoping Dormammu keeps his promise (as he does in the comics).

Then, too, Strange still has the Time Gem. If Dormammu tries again, it’s quite possible that Strange would just put him back in the loop. That would serve as a strong deterrent, even if Dormammu is not magically bound to his promise.

Comment: So the answer is basically "Dormammu is an inter-dimensional super entity of his word"?